# TYPO3: Uncaught Error: Class not found any class want to use always give me this error

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I am trying to build an extension. In this extension, I'm trying to connect to the database of TYPO3 but I can't access this class and any class is always not found

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

class rpc {

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $tsc_Endpoint = '';

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $tsc_tokenID = '';

    /**
     * The main method of the backend module
     */
    public function main(){
        $connection = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
            ConnectionPool::class)
            ->getConnectionForTable('gpi_configurations');

        $queryBuilder = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
        $query = $queryBuilder
            ->select('*')
            ->from('gpi_configurations')
            ->where('config_name = tsc_Endpoint');

        $rows = $query->execute->fetchRows();
        print_r($rows);


        $client = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(GpiClient::class);
        try {
            $server = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(JsonRpc::class)->__construct($client);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
        echo  $server->process();

    }


}

    $q = new rpc();
    $q->main();
```

I want to mention something this bulk of code in a file called rpc.php

Is there a way to access TYPO3 functionality on rpc.php? I did many searches but I did not find any useful help.

[installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xtzo.png)
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOkUt.png)

Answer (score 1):

## Full edit:

From our conversation below, I think what you need is a `Middleware` to provide an endpoint. This endpoint reads data from the TYPO3-database passes them your your rpc-service and returns some JSON as `$response`.

- To ensure autoloading, all your PHP-code should go into the `Classes/` folder.
- You have to use `namespace Mazen\YourExtensionName\...` in your Classes.
- I would recommend to make your rpc-class a service and put it into `Classes/Service/` but I might not know enough about your application.
- Read the Docs about `TYPO3 Doctrine`, especially the part about the `WHERE clause`.
- Reading and learning some basic priceless about TYPO3 Extension Development might be a good idea.

### Middleware

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestHandling/Index.html
- German, but a nice snippet for a Mailchimp endpoint: https://various.at/news/typo3-tipps-und-tricks-psr-15-mideelware-am-beispiel-mailchimp-webhook#c971

### Doctrine

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html#where-andwhere-and-orwhere

### Services

The Service API it self is deprecated, but you still can group some parts of your application into service ans load them with Dependency Injection from everywhere you need them.

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html

### TYPO3 Extension Development

- Developing TYPO3 Extensions: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/Index.html

Comment: thanks a lot, @nito maybe I did not get you. I need to know 1- if I want to use typo3 core functionality outside the Classes folder is that possible or not ?? 2- I assume that can possibly How to do that, How to extend typo3 classes? the problem is that the folder vendor path is not included in autoload_classmap.php 
I update the post please check the second image
I'm really appreciated your answer :)

Comment: 1. Which TYPO3 version do you use? 2. Did you install it with composer?

Comment: TYPO3 version 10.4 I installed it by GUI wizard -> download and copy to xxamp htdocs folder and run the installer I'm not using install via composer

Comment: When you just download a archive and run it without executing any composer command, then you got a TYPO3 in "Classic mode".

Comment: In your code snippet it seems that you want to provide an JSON-API to read data from the TYPO3 database, is that right? Do you want provide this endpoint cached or uncached?

Comment: the problem is if I try to extend any class from core always give me not found like this 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility' not found
what does this mean? 
I'll edit the question with a screenshot
the endpoint will be uncached

Comment: How do you call the file that holds your rpc class?

Comment: I'm trying to call RPC.php class through Jquery in file .html and status code in network 200 but response throw exception not found

    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (window.efx && window.efx.init) {
                efx.startup("models/tsc/rpc.php");
                efx.init();
            }
});
    });

Comment: Yup, that will not work. You don't use TYPO3 to execute your PHP, you execute your PHP directly and just want to use some classes from TYPO3 without all the TYPO3 bootstraping. But you need this bootstraping for the autoloading and putting everything together. I'll edit my answer later with a few hints how to do it in TYPO3.

Comment: waiting for your hints I have lost days in this issue I'm appreciated your help  @nito

Comment: I totally rewrote my answer into an suggestion what I believe that might help you the most to achieve what you want.